# How Service-oriented architecture and Component-based development relate to each other?

Tags: architecture, components, soa

Here is a pretty theoretical and abstract question: How Service-oriented architecture (SOA) differs from Component-based approach? Is the concept of SOA an extension to Component-based approach?

What are your thoughts? Maybe you know any good papers that cover this subject?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two concepts are pretty orthogonal, neither complementing nor contradicting each other. If you threatened to stick a rusty fork in my eye and forced me to generalise, I'd say that component-based development was a technique for modelling and assembling a specific piece of software, where as SOA is a technique for organising separate systems so they can talk to each other.

Like I said, a crass generalisation, but it's all I'm going to give you without a more specific question :)

Answer (score 13):

In [this article](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/dw/rational/pdf/2169.pdf) the authors view component-based development as supporting SOA - in the end your SOA needs **services** to be implemented and you design **components** as the deliverables which provide the implementation. Some of the skill being to get the granularity and cohesiveness of the components right.

I believe that this perspective is a reasonable characterisation of how SOA is actually done today. For me the key is you first focus on services, what you need to do in a business sense, then later come to the component designs. [Here's an [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-soa-design1/) about identifying services. Disclaimer: I'm an IBM person, these articles are written by colleagues.]

However, if you wind the clock back I think you will find that Component-Based Development was an approach which predates SOA, and had many of the same goals as SOA. I view as unduly cynical the opinion that SOA is just marketing hype, sticking new labels on old concepts. However there is considerable overlap between CBD and SOA. I just view SOA as being the best collective wisdom we have to date on how to do integration, no doubt as we learn more new techniques will emerge until the overall kitbag merits a new name again.

My personal view is that SOA got momentum because a set of technologies emerged that allowed disparate technical teams within an organisation (eg. an IBM base and Microsoft base) to build components that could use each others services. In other words a level of maturity in how to do components emerged, such that a new label (SOA) was attractive.

Answer (score 4):

One might say that SOA is a high-level form of component-based development, where components have been turned into reusable pieces of functionality called services.

Answer (score 0):

Component Based Development required a repository of code fragments (sometimes complete object stacks) generally in one code syntax. To be useful on anything else these fragments would be required to be ported or called across a common interface (say windows API or COM, COM+ et al) between VB6 & VC++ for example. Thus VC++ functions could be used and called by VB6. Thus component reuse sometimes required a whole lot of refactoring to be reused which was counter intuitive. There was also the problem of early and late binding. The repository components still needed to be built and deployed as a functioning part of the code base in order to be used. The code should've been unit tested before adding to the repository but still required integration testing to confirm functionality. You'd also have to construct the correct parameters in order to "cross the object interface". Again, this generally required wrapper code.

These code repositories might not include everything to be truly cross platform. Platform independence is usually required when problems are segmented across domains, especially in integrated systems. The interface is included in the built and deployed software, not the actual functioning code.

What you are missing between the two is a Framework. SOA is not CBDv2 nor an extension to it, you have to go through the framework of the service implementation. Frameworks are not a new concept either.

Both CBD & SOA ultimately promote code reuse. CBD is generally narrower in scope than SOA! SOA needs a framework to be effective, CBD doesn't. CBD is coupled to its development language and target platform.